# AppAuth - external browser window wont open?

Tags: ios, objective-c, appauth

i am using the AppAuth library for a custom single sign-on in my app written in objective c.

So far i have managed to get it to work in swift but when i use the same code converted to objective c the browser is not opened. This is what i have so far (have removed all urls and ids from the code included here, so dont mind that the strings are empty here):

In App Delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong, nullable) id<OIDExternalUserAgentSession> currentAuthorizationFlow;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)options {
// Sends the URL to the current authorization flow (if any) which will process it if it relates to
// an authorization response.
if ([_currentAuthorizationFlow resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithURL:url]) {
    _currentAuthorizationFlow = nil;
    return YES;
}

return NO;
}
```

And in viewcontroller:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonAction:(id)sender {
NSURL *authorizationEndpoint = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
NSURL *tokenEndpoint = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];

OIDServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[OIDServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithAuthorizationEndpoint:authorizationEndpoint tokenEndpoint:tokenEndpoint];

NSString *clientId = @"";
NSURL *redirectUri = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];

OIDAuthorizationRequest *builder = [[OIDAuthorizationRequest alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration clientId:clientId scopes:@[OIDScopeOpenID] redirectURL:redirectUri responseType:OIDResponseTypeCode additionalParameters:nil];

// performs authentication request
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = [OIDAuthState authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest:builder presentingViewController:self callback:^(OIDAuthState *_Nullable authState, NSError *_Nullable error) {
    if (authState) {
        NSLog(@"Got authorization tokens. Access token: %@", authState.lastTokenResponse.accessToken);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Authorization error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
}
```

This opens up an alert asking the user if he/she wants to sign in, and if i press continue an external browser should open with the custom SSO page. The problem is that nothing happens after pressing continue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters in your config and request, particularly the issuer.
Not storing currentAuthorizationFlow also stopped my flow dead.

hth.